# Is there a way to Split strings in a google sheet cell into multiple rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to Split strings in a google sheet cell into multiple rows?
Example:

```
Current:
Oranges       Drums        8       9
Mangos        Guitars
Grapes        Piano

Expected:
Oranges       Drums        8       9

Mangos        Guitars      8       9

Grapes        Piano        8       9

Thank you.
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data is much more easier to process than what assumed based on the post.

#### Try this:

`=query(query({transpose(split($A$1, char(10))),transpose(split($B$1, char(10)))}, "select Col1, Col2, '"&$C$1&"', '"&$D$1&"'"), "offset 1", 0)`

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, this works =transpose(split(A1,CHAR(10)))
However it doesn’t auto populate the values 4 and 8 to match each row. As shown in the expected above.

Comment: I have updated my answer @KingMichaelKing, can you kindly check if it works on you?

Comment: Hi @KingMichaelKing, I have further updated the answer to fit in your expected output. Sorry for the hassle. Can you kindly check again?

Comment: i tried but getting the following errors Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 3. Valid values are between 0 and 2 inclusive.
Thanks once again for all your help :)

Comment: Hi @KingMichaelKing, can you share a sample of your sheet? I may have missed something, and would like to test the formula on an actual sheet you prepared. Possibly on the data that the formula errors out.

Comment: Hi @KingMichaelKing, that should do it. Kindly see updated answer.

Comment: I tried summing the values but the sum values return 0. Any idea how i can still sum the values? I would also like to use SUMIFS to check however i think the values are seen as char.. any work around? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228899/discussion-between-nazia-and-king-michael-king).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I've met this problem before and I had a simple but not very elegant solution for this:

```
=if(C8<>"",C8,E7)
```

[image: On the picture you see values separated by semicolons - it's my regional setting (Poland). Most of the world should use comma.]

Simply - I check whether columns on my left are empty. If I find some values there, I copy contents, if these columns on left are empty I copy values from above.

This solution requires to copy down all the IF formulas.